# The number of positive integers

Tags: probability

The number of positive integers $abcd$ that have four digits such that $d\not=0$ and $a\not=0$
and number $4$ divide both  $abcd$ and $dbca$ ?

My attempt:

[image]

Comment: here is my attempt like the question before :http://www.arab4load.info/uploads/02_131362254763161.png

Comment: Yes, that looks okay.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott not quite ok at the end, more justification is needed

Comment: @Theta30: I disagree: it’s clear at that point that the OP understands what to do and has either seen the odd/even dependence or simply checked the other cases by hand. Were I grading it in a course in which it’s likely to be asked, I’d probably give $9$ out of $10$, with a comment that a more explicit justification of that bit would be preferable. That’s almost certainly not a course in which fully detailed proofs are expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look first at $abcd$. If $d=2$, there are $5$ possibilities for $c$, namely the odd digits. If $d=4$, again we have $5$ possibilities for $c$, namely the even digits, and so on, for a total of $20$. The same analysis applies to $dcba$, for a total of $400$. The above way of counting is essentially the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

if $c$ is even, then $a$ and $d$ are 4 or 8;
if $c$ is odd, then $a$ and $d$ are 2 or 6;
b is irrelevant,

for each $b$ and each $c$ there are 4 possible $a$'s and $d$'s: 10*10*4 = 400